# Clarification to plot timeseries data in python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have data as follows:

```
2831    2016-07-13 06:08:41
2832    2016-07-14 17:07:58
2834    2016-07-15 10:12:40
2837    2016-07-14 08:38:38
2839    2016-11-07 04:47:00
2840    2016-11-07 10:01:00
2842    2016-07-14 07:48:31
```

There are 10000+ data like this. I need to plot all these data in a histogram for 24 hrs. These are basically the website hit timings of a particular website. So need to get the frequency at which the website is being hit like between which hour there is most hits.

Here is what I tried:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np sns.set(); np.random.seed(0) x = 
Cancelled_city_pickup_draft ax = sns.distplot(Cancelled_city_pickup_draft,bins=1)
```

But while running im getting error "TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('

Comment: You want to draw histogram on 24 hours in a day? or hit counts by day in the data frame?

Comment: also please include the code you have

Comment: quang-hoang.. i need  to  plot the hsitogram for 24 hrs in a day and to find out where n when the hits are most... for eg  say 350 hits btwn 1 pm and 2pm (all days put together) and 550 hits between 2 pm and 3 pm and so  on for all 24  hrs a day

Comment: Cripcate...Here is the code that  i had written.. Just a basic one..

import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = Cancelled_city_pickup_draft
ax = sns.distplot(Cancelled_city_pickup_draft,bins=1)